# easy algorithm for using flags

Tags: algorithm

Exists flags defs:

```
flag1=1
flag2=2
flag3=4
flag4=8
...
flagN=2^(N-1)

flag=flag1+flag2+...+flagN
```

if `flagI` not set, it eq `0`

i have `flag`. which method can easily check, is for example `flag2` defined?

Comment: Depending on your language ... A shift operation `flagN= 1<<(N-1)` is a lot cheaper and faster than a multiplication or exponantiation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to your question

What's the range of `flag`? If it's under 2^64-1, almost every method is okay.

As @taskinoor posted, you should  notice that:

> ```
> flag1 = 000 ... ... 0001 
>
> flag2 = 000 ... ... 0010 
>
> flag3 = 000 ... ... 0100
> ```

In other words,

```
flag[n] = 1 << (n-1)
```

So, if you want to check  all bits, a `for` loop and `bitwise operation` are fast enough to solve you problem. Like This (suppose you could understand *C/C++* and flag is less than 2^32, which could be hold by an `unsigned int` in *C/C++*):

```
void check(unsigned int flag)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    if ((flag & (1 << i)) != 0)
      printf("flag%d defined!\n", i+1);
}
```

It's O(k), which k is the length of the type of `flag` in binary. For `unsigned int`, it's O(32) = O(1), almost in constant time.

## If you just want to count how many flags defined:

I don't know what's your purpose. If you just want to count how many flags defined and `flag` is less than 2^64, the following method is awesome(suppose `unsigned int` as well):

```
unsigned int count_bit(unsigned int x)
{
  x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
  x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
  x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
  x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);
  x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) + ((x >> 16)& 0x0000FFFF);
  return x;
}
```

If you call count_bit(1234567890), it'll return 12.

Let me explain this algorithm.

This algorithm is based on `Divide and Conquer Algorithm`. Suppose there is a 8bit integer 213(11010101 in binary), the algorithm works like this(each time merge two neighbor blocks):

```
+-------------------------------+
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  <- x
|  1 0  |  0 1  |  0 1  |  0 1  |  <- first time merge
|    0 0 1 1    |    0 0 1 0    |  <- second time merge
|        0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1        |  <- third time ( answer = 00000101 = 5)
+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that in each flag only one bit is set to 1, others are 0.

```
flag1 = 000 ... ... 0001
flag2 = 000 ... ... 0010
flag3 = 000 ... ... 0100
// and like this
```

So if you do bitwise AND `flag & flag2` then the result will be non-zero only if `flag2` is defined.

```
r = flag & flag2;
if r != 0 then flag2 is defined
```

You can do this with all flags.

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean isSet (flags, flagN){
   Return (flags & flagN) != 0;
}
```

Flags being the flag vector, flagN the flag you want to check

Answer (score 0):

It is worth grokking the concept of bitmasks and flags more deeply. You can then use your imagination to represent state efficiently .  (Just an example explained below)

```
 First -Define the bitmask :          0x0000001c
```

What are the binary strings for which when you do an 'and' operation on the mask, you get a non-zero value?

Those are your valid flag values.

Valid flag values for this bitmask:  `0x0000001c,0x00000014,0x00000018,0x00000004,0x00000008,etc  ..`

So, in your application if you can do the following:

```
flagvariable |= flagvalue1  ->Enable a particular flag.  
if( flagvariable & maskvalue)   :Check if a mask is enabled  :
```

Then the different cases you  would need to check :

```
if(flagvariable &maskvalue ==flagvalue1)    { do something}
else  
if(flagvariable &maskvalue ==flagvalue2) {do something else}    

flagvariable &= `flagvalue1  : Clear the flag
```

To be more clear about flags and bitmasks, just step into gdb and do  p /t  and  evaluate the the operations described above.